# Split a row into several rows while maintaining formulae

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID1        |ID2      |     Month 1   |    Month 2    |    Month 3    |Analysis
Item Number|Item type|column1|column2|column1|column2|column1|column2|Ac1m1|Ac1M2
```

The practice has been to add each month's data as new columns inserted before the final Analysis. We then add a column in the Analysis field that is basically applying a formula to some of the new columns inserted. We also have some other sheets that are linked to the data provided in the Analysis.

As time passes and we have more months it's a little hectic to maintain and not very intuitive so I was thinking of changing the format to something like this:

Item Number|Item type|column1|column2|Month|Analysis

The `Item Number` and `Item type` will be duplicated for each month and the rest of the columns will be unique.

What I want to do is change the format while maintaining all the linked formulas, so is there an easy way to do this? Also, is this the best way to represent this data?

*@momobo* the Analysis is basically a formula. We usually take two types of reading each both automatically and locally, one of the columns in the Analysis checks to see we did get a reading on that particular month. We also check the variance in the reading between local reading and automatic reading. The report (on separate other pages) eventually tells me how many readings were taken for each month, which items have not been measured and how long has it been since the last measurement. The report is directly linked to the Analysis columns but I am not using the rest of the table anywhere else outside the sheet.

*@Scheballs* the actual table is too wide to fit here. the actual table looks a lot like I posted, the only differences may be that the number of columns for each month is greater. If I break down each month's sub-column they'll look like this.

|                       MONTH1                     |
| AR1 | LR1 | AR2 | LR2 | Date | Done by | Remarks |

AR1,     Automatic reading for the first sensor, it is a number.
LR1,     local reading for the first sensor, it is a number.
Date,    the date when the reading took place.
Done By, the person who has done the reading (Assuming a local reading is available)
Remarks, just general remarks that do not feature in my analysis at this point.

The Analysis column would then look something like this:

|R1M1|R2M1|V1M1|V2M1|Detail|Count|

R1M1, Binary value, 1 if sensor 1 was read on month 1, 0 otherwise.
R2M1, Binary value, 1 if sensor 2 was read on month 1, 0 otherwise.
V1M1, the difference between the local and automatic reading for sensor 1 on month 1.
V2M1, the difference between the local and automatic reading for sensor 2 on month 1.
Count, the number of sensors read (either automatically or manually) per month.

Comment: We need more details. What kind of Analysis is it? Is a formula or a number? There is only one analysis per item. In your new format you will have analysis per item per month. What the other sheet wants?

Comment: Yeah, can you give us some sample data on how it looks now, how the formulas are calculating now, and then what you would want them to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an easy way - simply select data in question - then control+H - this = find & replace.

find "=" and replace with "A="

Do your moving around as necessary and then select data again and "Control+H" and find A= and replace with "="

Walla!